# do mirrorless camera lenses have automatic diaphragms

Tags: lens-design, mirrorless

Do mirrorless cameras have lenses with automatic diaphragms like DSLRs or are you able to focus and view through the working aperture because of their electronic viewfinders?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Re "What problem": It affects whether the depth of field is the same in the viewfinder as in the picture (in DSLRs it generally isn't), and whether you will be affected by [focus shift](https://photographylife.com/what-is-focus-shift). Isn't that a fair question for a photography site? (Unfortunately I don't know the answer.)

Comment: If it's that, the answer is the DoF preview button which exists on most, of not all, DSLRs. Alternatively, it could be something else entirely, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @PhilipKendall the question is about mirrorless cameras, not dSLRs.

Comment: My Panasonic GX-7, with all the mft lenses I have, stops the lens down as you change the aperture setting (i.e., performs stop-down metering) and DoF is accurate in liveview at all times. My Panasonic G3 doesn't and meters wide open, like a dSLR.

Answer (score 3):

**It varies.** Even when using the same camera, the lense can affect this feature, so if it's important to you, you're going to need to do your research. On my camera for example, three of my lenses can do DOF preview, but one of them can't for some unknown reason. This is not a standard feature and may be available or unavailable depending on the camera body, lense, and other settings.